# iron-session for database encryption, pros and cons

Tags: node.js, database, encryption-symmetric, better-sqlite3

I'm planning to use encryption to keep sensitive data of my users secure in sqlite3.  While thinking of an approach, I'm considering storing all the sensitive date in a single table field as an encrypted JSON object.  I will be using iron-session, but using their seal and unseal methods for this which bypasses the cookie sessions.

One concern I have is whether this would add significant amounts of overhead in processing, memory, and additional database writes.  I can't find much about this issue, so I'm asking the community.

I am using Nodejs with better-sqlite3 for database calls.  I haven't written the code yet, so here's the anticipated flow of handling routes that access this encrypted data.

```
How the field may look unencrypted:
{
    firstName: "Tito",
    lastName: "Puente",
    address: "580 Park Avenue, New York, NY 10036",
    email: tito@puente.com  //etc
}

Getting encrypted data.
1) better-sqlite to get encrypted string from database.
2) unseal with iron-session
3) unpack data from JSON and populate the res object.

Changing a field.
1) get encrypted field from DB.
2) unseal
3) assemble a new json object with all old information and the new updates.
4) seal
5) overwrite the same field on the database.
```

I would use a separate password for database encryption, so other encryption passwords can be rotated.

What performance differences would this model above have compared to a more horizontal approach with each field being its own encrypted value?